# Hide Date But Show Time (Format)

Tags: powerbi

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTan8.png)

I am trying to remove the dates  and leave the hours can somebody direct me in the right direction please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Highlight the column and in the format box on the ribbon, type HH:mm

[image]